# View draw complete callback

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, textview, android-viewtreeobserver

What event signifies that the draw of a `View` is complete?

I know about `ViewTreeObserver` listeners, but I couldn't find the 'final' one, which indicates, that the job is done.

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve ?

Comment: unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear - `What event signifies that the draw of a TextView is complete?`

Comment: I have a method which justifies text in a textview, so basically I call setText() first and then call this method. The issue is that the justification method starts too fast and gets inconsistent data from TextView with methods like getLineCount(). If I  set a delay in 500 ms after setText() and before calling justify method everything works fine. But I would like to set up a listener instead which would signal me that I can laund justification and not set a manual delay.

Comment: can you post some code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What event signifies that the draw of a TextView is complete?

There is no such hook for View class (or TextView). There is, however, [`onDraw()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas)) method which is called when the view should render its content.

So you can do:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    // Finished drawing. Do other stuff.
    // However you must check if this is the first or subsequent call.
    // Each call to "invalidate()" will trigger re-drawing.
}
```

Comment: When the device supports hardware acceleration, View rendering will be done in the asynchronous thread RenderThread, Is onDraw can correctly get the rendering is complete?

Answer (score 8):

`yourView.post(someRunnable)` ensures, that `someRunnable` will be executed after the view is laid out and drawn.

Comment: This is incorrect. All that View.post(Runnable) does is to post a message to the main thread. It does not wait for the view to laid out and drawn.

Comment: @Enselic, you are correct. But there cannot be scenario, when `post(Runnable)` will be executed before view has been laid out, because the view layout is also `Message` itself that is posted on `MessageQueue`. The runnable is posted **after** this message, hence it's not theoretically possible that the runnable will get executed **before** the view is laid out.

Comment: Maybe, but the answer is still very misleading. If you `View.post(Runnable)` right after inflating it, the `Runnable` will run before `View.onDraw()` is even called. I just tested it. `View.post(Runnable)` will SOMETIMES work, but it is definitely not a reliable method.

Comment: First thing I've found so far that works without having to override `onDraw()`.  I just have to nest successive calls to `post()`, which makes my code a little ugly.  But what can I say--it works.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly the method you are looking for is `onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)`. Or else you could try the `onPostResume()` method.